# Adding column with Yes/No values based on date of another column

Tags: r, date

```
ID  Date       
1   2020-06-03
2   2018-05-04
3   2019-08-09
```

I want to add a column to this data frame that indicates Yes/No based on whether or not the Date falls within the last year based on the date the code is being run.

```
ID  Date         YN
1   2019-06-03   Yes
2   2018-05-04   No
3   2019-06-02   No
```

Comment: what do you mean by *within the last year*?

Comment: @Onyambu based on the example it looks like Alice means within the last 365 (or 366 on leap year) days

Comment: If I'm running the script on June 3, 2020, then every Date between June 3 2019-June 3, 2020, would classify as "Yes." If I'm running on June 4, 2020, then a Date that is June 3, 2019, would classify as "No."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use base R for this, no need for additional packages, the year has approximately 365.25 days but you need to add 1 day to have the time elapsing within a year. Take the difference between today using `Sys.Date()` and what is in `d1[["Date"]]`. `diff.time()` can be applied to vectors. You'll need to get creative with leap years though.

I also realized that you don't specify whether the column `Date` is of `Date` format or just a `character` vector. If the latter, then you need to convert the column `Date` to `Date` format using `as.Date()`. `inherits(x, 'Date')` checks whether a vector `x` inherits the class `Date`. Assume `d1` is the name assigned to your `data.frame` object:

```
# in case 'Date' is a string, convert it to date:
if(!inherits(d1[["Date"]], "Date")) d1[["Date"]] <- as.Date(d1[["Date"]])

d1[["YN"]] <- ifelse(difftime(Sys.Date(), d1[["Date"]], units="days") <= 366.25, "Yes", "No")
```

Result:

```
> d1
  ID       Date  YN
1  1 2019-06-03 Yes
2  2 2018-05-04  No
3  3 2019-06-02  No
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
nw <- ymd("2020-06-03")
df %>%
  mutate(Date = ymd(Date),
         yn = if_else(nw > Date & Date >= nw - years(1), "Yes", "No"))         

  ID       Date  YN  yn
1  1 2019-06-03 Yes Yes
2  2 2018-05-04  No  No
3  3 2019-06-02  No  No
```

Comment: @slava-kohut what exactly do you mean by that? I just copy pasted the data into R

Comment: Your code starts with a `df` variable. The author provided a string.

Comment: @slava-kohut OP provided a dataframe. Not a string. at at the data provided. It has columns. Also OP said *I want to add a column to this dataframe*, which means they have a dataframe and not a string. Is your issue related to O's problem or is it that you have copied the data but doesn't know how to make that a dataframe?